# Dreaded Integrity constraint violation when completing sales orders

Tags: foreign-key-constraint

I've read tons of forum posts on this topic, but they all seem to be specific to the module or process and I can't find this one. How would I go about trouble-shooting and fixing this?

Here is the full error:

PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bitnami_magento`.`sales_invoice`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_INVOICE_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) at /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:90

Comment: I have figured out that I can Authorize a credit card and that creates an order. I can then invoice the order and there are no problems, but if I set payment to Authorize and Capture, the FK constraint fails because the order entry hasn't been created yet. Why would the invoice be created before the order, and is there a way to fix that?

Comment: which Credit Card Payment method are you using? Could be a bug

Comment: Using Rootways Extension for Authorize.net. I have also gotten the same error with Paypal Express Checkout. Same integrity constraint violation, so I dont think its in Rootways code.

Comment: I can also confirm the same problem with paypal - authorize works, authorize and capture does not. And Flexiti (financing payment option) only has option for authorize and capture, but I get the same SALES_INVOICE_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID foreign key violation issue.